# Errors lazy loading failed for package 'rgoogleads'

Tags: r, installation, package

im trying to install the rgoogleads but i get this error

```
* installing *source* package 'rgoogleads' ...
** package 'rgoogleads' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 2.5.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.0.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rgoogleads'
* removing 'C:/Users/jj/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rgoogleads'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgoogleads’ had non-zero exit status
```

What do I need to do to avoid this error?

Comment: You need to update library "cli". install.packages("cli"). You use version 2.5.0, but minimum 3.0.0 is required.

Comment: how do i update cli? I clicked on it in packages and updated it but im still getting the same error and it is making me restart session in a loop

Comment: Restart R, then the first thing you should run is `install.packages("cli")` before you load any other packages.

Comment: i did this but everytime i download the package it is still version 2.5

Comment: Is it possible you have some code that automatically runs when you start R? Like something in your R profile? When you first start R and run `sessionInfo()` does it show that `cli` has already been loaded?

Comment: loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.4.1     compiler_3.6.0 R6_2.4.0       cli_2.5.0      tools_3.6.0